# Python, Is there a way to use list comprehension to form a list of 10 random floats between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, random, list-comprehension

I am a beginner to python (or coding in general!) and I am currently learning list comprehension.
What I want to ask is if there exists a method to generate an array of floats between 0 and 1 using only list comprehension.
The output should give the same result as :

```
for a in range(100):
    i = random()
    list.append(i)
print(list)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: At first: list comprehensions create lists, not arrays (different type). Besides of that, show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: On a second note,  you are overwriting the builtin list function in your example,  you should not do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[random.random() for _ in range(100)]`

This is an unusual case where you don't need a variable for the `for`. It's conventional to use `_` to represent that.